# Operation that return true if all leaves in the tree equal to their parents

Tags: c#, tree, binary-tree

hi I tried to this but its not work , I need to write operation that return true if all leaves in the tree equal to their parents value  , please help I have test , maybe its a Main Problem?

Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinNode<int> t1, t2, bt1, bt2, bt;

        t1 = new BinNode<int>(3);
        t2 = new BinNode<int>(3);
        t2.SetLeft(new BinNode<int>(null, 3, new BinNode<int>(3)));
        bt1 = new BinNode<int>(t1, 3, t2);
        bt1 = new BinNode<int>(null, 3, bt1);
       t1 = new BinNode<int>(3);
        t2 = new BinNode<int>(3);
        t2.SetLeft(new BinNode<int>(3));
        t2.SetRight(new BinNode<int>(new BinNode<int>(3), 3, null));
        bt2 = new BinNode<int>(t1, 3, t2);
        bt = new BinNode<int>(bt1, 3, bt2);

        Console.WriteLine(SumTree(bt));
        Console.WriteLine(LeafCounter(bt));
        Console.WriteLine(CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(bt));
        Console.WriteLine(IsLeafEqualHisFather(bt));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Operation:

```
 public static  bool IsLeafEqualHisFather(BinNode<int> Head)
    {
        if (Head != null)
        {
            if (IsLeaf(Head))
                return true;
            if (IsLeaf(Head.GetRight()) == true && (Head.GetRight().GetValue() == Head.GetValue()) || IsLeaf(Head.GetLeft()) == true && (Head.GetLeft().GetValue() == Head.GetValue()))
            {
                return IsLeafEqualHisFather(Head.GetRight()) && IsLeafEqualHisFather(Head.GetLeft());
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you experiencing an issue? If so, what is it?

Comment: A tree node cannot be equal to its parent.  You need to rethink what you are trying to do.  (Or what you were assigned to do, more likely.)  If you need to ***validate*** a tree to make sure that it contains no nodes that are equal to their parents, you should state that in the question.

Comment: @MikeNakis I don't think the OP is talking about the nodes having reference equality, just that the held values of the nodes are equal, and it's certainly possible for parent and child nodes to have equal values depending on how you construct the tree.

Comment: @juharr your *interpretation* is probably right, but it requires ignoring the literal statement of the question and hypothesizing as to what the OP really meant to write when he wrote something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to first check if the given node is null or a leaf.  If not then you need to determine if the left and right nodes are null and if not if they are leaves or sub-trees.  If they are leaves then you need to compare the value to the head, or if they are sub-trees you need to recursively call the method on the sub-tree.

```
public static  bool AllLeavesEqualToParent(BinNode<int> Head)
{
    if (Head == null)
        return false; // no leaves and no parent.

    if (IsLeaf(Head))
        return false; // head is a leaf, so there is no parent.

    var right = head.GetRight();
    var left = head.GetLeft();
    if(left != null) 
    {
        if (IsLeaf(left))
        {
            if (left.GetValue() != Head.GetValue())    
                return false; // left leaf didn't match
        }
        else if(!AllLeavesEqualToParent(left))
            return false; // left sub tree has leaf that doesn't match parent.
    }

    if(right!= null) 
    {
        if (IsLeaf(right))
        {
            if (right.GetValue() != Head.GetValue())    
                return false; // right leaf didn't match
        }
        else if(!AllLeavesEqualToParent(right))
            return false; // right sub tree has leaf that doesn't match parent.
    }

    return true; //Both left and right are either null (but not both), a leaf that matches
                 // the head, or sub trees with all leaves that match their parents.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , you are the best , nice thinking:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main issue here is that you only perform the recursive check if that whole big `if` expression evaluates to `true`. But that will only be true if you're already looking at leaves, so if you're starting at the top of a large tree, you're out of look.

Let's simplify it - check whether the left passes the test. This means one of the following:
1. The left node is `null`
2. The left node is a leaf and has the same value as the current node
3. The left node is not a leaf and passes the `IsLeafEqualHisFather` test.

The repeat the same for the right. Then check whether they both passed or not.

Side note: there is (almost) never to use `[something] == true`. `[something]` serves that purpose all on its own.

```
public static  bool IsLeafEqualHisFather(BinNode<int> current)
{
    if (current != null)
    {
        if (IsLeaf(current))
        {
            return true;
        }

        var currentValue = current.GetValue();

        var left = current.GetLeft();
        var leftPasses = left == null || 
            IsLeaf(left) ? left.GetValue() == currentValue : IsLeafEqualHisFather(left);

        var right = current.GetRight();
        var rightPasses = right == null || 
            IsLeaf(right) ? left.GetValue() == currentValue : IsLeafEqualHisFather(left));

        return leftPasses && rightPasses;            
    }

    return false;
}
```